# How to set the datepicker in html5 selection from current date onwards?

Tags: html

I have used the date of html5

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="datee" placeholder="Date" required>
```

I want to  set here selection from current date onwards. How to do that ?  Can anyone say how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure javascript as html5 input does not provide any other way to add the current date unless you specify with the format dd-mm-yyyy.

So here is the javascript code that will fill the input with the current date.

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('datee').valueAsDate = new Date();
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to hide the previous dates from the date picker from the current date

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```html
<?php
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d");
?>
<input type="date" min="<?php echo $current_date?>">

<p>For example, we will set the min date manually to "2017-11-24"</p>

<input type="date" min="2017-11-24">
```

You can also set max value.